# how to ignore transparant area of the image

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0, opencv3.1

I have an image with 4 channels BGRA.
I want to check my image if there is value **in the 4th channel**.
Then I want to get values from the area that have value in the 4th channel.
I want to get the same image within values from the area that have value in the 4th channel.
I want to ignore and make other areas zero.

It's like that:
There is a image. some part of image fully transparant. 
And I want to make zero in transparant area. Because I'll use this image for cv:add method.

I hope you understood.

how can I do like that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Users are much more likely to help if you show some [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on your own. Please provide a [mre] to your _specific_ problem. Show any code you tried so far, and provide some clean sample input, and the expected output (even manually drawn).

Comment: use the inRange function to find all pixels as a mask and then use setTo function to set them to (0,0,0,0)